# cakephp validate without save()

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm trying to use CakePHP validation without using `save()`.
But it always returns errors. I insert text, but validation says it is empty. Why?

My Model:

```
var $validate = array(
    'm_subject' => array(           
        'empty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Subject is empty',
        )
    ),
    'm_text' => array(
        'empty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Text is empty',
        )
    )
);
```

In my Controller:

```
$this->Admin->set($this->data);
if($this->Admin->validates($this->data, array('m_subject', 'm_text'))) {
    //OK
}
else {          
    $errors = $this->Admin->invalidFields();
    pr($errors); //Always returns "Subject is empty" and "Text is empty".
}
```

Comment: Try my solution as it worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

In both [CakePHP 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) and [CakePHP 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html#validating-data-from-the-controller)

`$this->ModelName->validates();` does not take an array of data if you are passing anything to `validates()` it is an array of options that is then processed by the modelCallback `beforeValidates()`

Instead try this logic if you wish to determine if data is valid:

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->data);
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // Data Validated
} else {
    // Data Not Validated
}
```

Answer (score 2):

thats because you shouldnt use required in this context.
it needs to have those fields present in $this->data otherwise.

read the part about it here:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/

oh, now i see the problem. you are using validates() incorrectly! you need to set the data first:

```
$this->User->set($this->data);
$res = $this->User->validates();
```

but thats pretty good documented...

Comment: $this->data - all data get from post method

Comment: I add this "$this->User->set($this->data);", but is the same problems.

Comment: yes of course. as I just told you, the array needs to contain all "required" keys (which it probably doesnt). therefore you should drop those lines in your valdation arrays.

Answer (score 1):

On a similar note, [in CakePHP 2.0 Model](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelsave), there is a option for validation only on saveAll().

> validate: Set to false to disable validation, true to validate each record before saving, 'first' to validate all records before any are saved (default), or 'only' to only validate the records, but not save them.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Make sure that in view you have created form like this, if you are using cakephp's method to create form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create("Admin"); ?>
```

Here "Admin" is Model name.

Answer (score 0):

Assign

```
$this->data['ModelName']['m_subject'] = $this->data['ModelName']['m_subject']['name']
$this->data['ModelName']['m_text'] = $this->data['ModelName']['m_text']['name']
```

Because

As file upload is always an array and it will look like this.

```
 'm_subject' => array(
        'name' => 'foobar',
        'size' => 1234567,
        'error' => 0,
        ...
     )
```

So it will always give you error. As it is looking for string and found array.